# How to disable page turning（goback and forward） by Sliding left and right in flutter_webview_plugin?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm developing an app with flutter,but now I got stuck in a difficult problem 
(the app doesn't look like a native app,because the page can turning by sliding).
I don't want users to turn page by slide left or right at the edge of screen.
how to disable it with some code when I use FlutterWebviewPlugin?

FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

```
class _HomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> { 
    FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin(); 
    @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
        return new WebviewScaffold( 
            url: "http://www.google.com", 
            appBar: new AppBar( 
                title: new Text("google"), 
            ), 
        ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please include working example or some code related to your problem.

Comment: It's simple.Just like this:

class _HomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FlutterWebviewPlugin flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WebviewScaffold(
        url: "https://www.google.com",
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("google"),
        ),
      );
  }
}

Comment: And I want to disable this:
'turning page by slide left or right at the edge of screen'.